# Generate HTML file from Javascript for SEO

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I have a simple javascript function that fetches an RSS feed and displays it in an HTML document. This RSS feed is only updated once per day.

I want to be able to use the javascript function to create an html file that is stored in my htdocs folder and is generated once per day (so that the RSS feed is only accessed once per day).

Whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way to do it is a daily [CRON job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) executing a server-side script (PHP, shell scripts etc.) which uses an XML parsing library - all operating on the server.